# Get MP4 stream lengths

Tags: c++, directshow, mp4

I'm working in an app in wich we use IMediaDet to get stream lengths. Now we're starting to work with MP4 containers. The problem is, when I try an IMediaDet::put_fileName() with the MP4 file, I get HRESULT = -2147024770 (ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND). Using a comercial mp4 demuxer, I see the video stream uses mpg2 encoding.

My questions: How to get the stream length of a stream inside a MP4 container? Is there a way to make IMediaDet accept these files? Is there a way to point what demuxer IMediaDet should use?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.fourcc.org/ might help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, [DirectShow does not contain an MP4 parser, even in Windows 7](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/0a7f7ab9-19c1-4938-bc1a-d87c8f49da86).  In Win7, the MP4 functionality was added to media foundation.

So you have a few options.  You can buy or build a directshow filter that implements an MP4 demux and [associate it with the "mp4" file extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd377513%28VS.85%29.aspx), which should allow IMediaDet to properly demux the file.  Or you can use Media Foundation, which should be able to return this info.  Or you could use a separate library entirely for MP4 files, [like MP4v2](http://code.google.com/p/mp4v2/).  (note you could also implement an MP4 demux filter with MP4v2, if you want to use DirectShow instead of MP4v2 directly)