# QT: get video dimensions in QVideoWidget

Tags: qt, qmediaplayer

This should be something simple but I cannot figure this out. How can I get the video dimensions for a file that is loaded into QVideoWidget/QMediaPlayer. So, my code is as follows:

```
QMediaPlayer m_MediaPLayer(0, QMediaPlayer::VideoSurface);
m_VideoWidget = new QVideoWidget;
m_MediaPLayer.setVideoOutput(m_VideoWidget);
m_MediaPLayer.setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("file.avi"));

m_MediaPLayer.play();
// I am here checking for media status changed event
connect(&m_MediaPLayer,   SIGNAL(mediaStatusChanged(QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus)),
        this, SLOT(mediaStatusChanged(QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus)));

void MyClass::mediaStatusChanged(QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus status)
{
    // Here I get notification for media status change but no idea how to 
    // get the video size. I could not figure out a way. 

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In theory there are two ways to get this information:

1. Through [`QMediaPlayer::metaData`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaobject.html#metaData) using the key [`Resolution`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediametadata.html) you should get the resolution as `QSize`:

   ```
   if (m_MediaPLayer->isMetaDataAvailable()) {
     qDebug() <<"resolution:"  <<m_MediaPLayer->metaData("Resolution");
   }
   ```
2. Using [`QMediaResource.resolution()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaresource.html#resolution) which also returns a `QSize`:

   ```
   qDebug() << "resolution:" << m_MediaPLayer->media().canonicalResource().resolution();
   ```

However, in both cases it returns `-1,-1` for me for two videos I tried (one avi, and an mp4).

There are some old Qt threads about this problem: [get resolution of a video file](http://forum.qt.io/topic/31278/solved-get-resolution-of-a-video-file-40-qmediaplayer-41), and [QMediaPlayer resolution returns (-1x-1)](https://forum.qt.io/topic/32547/qmediaplayer-resolution-returns-1x-1/3). Although some solutions are given, none work for me, and in fact there is a [bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-28850) of this:

[**QTBUG-28850 - QMediaResource returns no media info**](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-28850)

which is still open.

Some related questions:

- [Get native video resolution of a video file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145730/get-native-video-resolution-of-a-video-file)
- [C++ : What's the easiest library to open video file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956/c-whats-the-easiest-library-to-open-video-file)
- [How to read video metadata (C/C++)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660321/how-to-read-video-metadata-c-c)

An [answer in the last question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6660331/1771479) suggests to use [**MediaInfo**](http://mediaarea.net/tr/MediaInfo), which contain libraries that can extract meta data of videos.

I expected [OpenCV](http://www.opencv.org) to be able to do this, however this [is not the case](http://answers.opencv.org/question/20826/how-can-i-extract-metadata-from-video/).

Comment: The second version does not work for me but if I use the first version in the event handler for the QMediaPlayer::BufferedMedia status, it returns the correct size. I will make this wortk for me and thanks for the very detailed answer.

Comment: Ok, I'm glad to hear that! Just one question, which OS are you using?

Comment: I am on Linux Mint 17, which is a fork of ubuntu 14.04, I think. I actually need to run it on an ARM based processor, so we will see how it goes later in the day but that is also running Ubuntu 14.04 (Tegra Jetson Tk1, NVIDIA).

Comment: Ok thanks, I am using Ubuntu 14.04, but it could be because of the videos I tried.

Comment: I am using gstreamer 1.2.4 as well. Perhaps, it has something to do with the backend. Also, I am getting the size in the `mediaStatusChanged` signal event handler. This could also be a reason.

Comment: has anyone on osx gotten QMediaPlayer::metaData to return anything?

Comment: WMV & Windows 10 & Qt 5.10.1 got QSize(-1, -1).

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem by replacing `QVideoWidget` with `QGraphicsView` + `QGraphicsVideoItem`. `QGraphicsVideoItem` has `nativeSize` property. But the tricky thing is that `nativeSize` becomes valid only after some time since you start playing video. The trick is to connect to special `QGraphicsVideoItem::nativeSizeChanged(const QSizeF &size)` signal that is emitted in case of real `nativeSize` obtainment.

Code sample:

```
 m_player.setVideoOutput(&m_graphicsItem);    // m_player is QMediaPlayer
 ui->videoView->setScene(new QGraphicsScene); // videoView is QGraphicsView
 ui->videoView->scene()->addItem(&m_graphicsItem);

 connect(&m_graphicsItem, &QGraphicsVideoItem::nativeSizeChanged, this, &MainWindow::calcVideoFactor);
```